# Next.js shallow routing

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a multi step form and would like my path to be changed depending on form step. I found out there is smth. like shallow routing which can be used for this purpose. So in my form step number zero component I added Router and the inscrease function.

```
    export default function ContractInfo({ formStep, prevFormStep, nextFormStep, selected }) {
    
      const router = useRouter();
      const { query } = router;
      const { formStepsNumer } = query;
    
      const increase = () => {
        var newStepNumber = + 1;
        router.push(`/?step=${newStepNumber}`, undefined, {
          shallow: true
        });
      };
........ more irrelevant code
```

Attention, I am not giving all the code, otherwise it will get too complicated. Before adding shallow routing, everything worked. Problem now is, that my URL gets changed onClick, as I wished, but the next form step won't render anymore.

```
..... above irrelevant code
 

    <div className="mt-3 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3">
                <a
                  //onClick={nextQuizStep}
                  onClick={() => nextFormStep(contracts?.[isSelected]), increase }
                  className="w-full flex items-center justify-center px-8 py-3 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-yellow-500 hover:bg-yallow-600 md:py-4 md:text-lg md:px-10"
                >
                  Next
                </a>
              </div>
```

Basically NextFormStep()which worked before, now is broken. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I had to write my function directly inside on onClick:

```
onClick={() => {
   nextFormStep(contracts?.[isSelected]);
   {router.push(`/?step=${+1}`, undefined, {
     shallow: true
   });
  }; 
 }
}
```

I know this code really is ugly. If you have any refractoring suggestions, please welcome!